# Which data service to buy for redistributable data?

Tags: data, tick-data

This is a follow-up to my previous question regarding anyone whom wanted to ['donate' data](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/1236/do-you-have-historical-tick-data-you-want-to-donate).

So far no one has stepped up *(learning more about buying and selling data, I realize that I'm going to have to buy the data if I want to re-sell it, or give it away for that matter - re: licensing agreements?)*

So I'm trying to determine a good source for data with a *relatively flexible licensing* agreement. So far the first place I've found is the [CME's distributor's service](http://www.cmegroup.com/market-data/distributor/) @ ~$12,000/yr starting.

If you sell historical data, know of data-feeds, etc., please let me know. I'll add it to this list, and we can discuss the pluses and negatives.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're addressing the wrong people.  What I'd do is to talk to the data vendors' marketing departments, much like I'm sure http://www.wikiposit.org/ has done.  Tell them you would like to offer (an excerpt of) their data, in a unified/post-processed form, you would be willing to include links back to their sales website, or praise the vendors somehow, e.g. have a voting system for the quality of the data.

I'm not a data vendor but I'm sure as long as you make it look like that's the best form of advertising they've ever had you should be able to negotiate a licensing model that allows you to at least show the data on your website.  I imagine this works particularly well with smaller or niche data providers.

Comment: thanks! that sounds like a plan. There are a lot of them out there- so that's why I posted it up here to see if I could get some recommendations!

Answer (score 5):

[xignite](http://xignite.com) seems like a cheaper option for historical data at around $6,000 per year.
I am not a client (yet) so I can't give my opinion but it looks good to me.
They have a long list of [services](http://www.xignite.com/Products/Catalog.aspx), a free trial period and interesting pricing model based on the number of queries you send them.
If you do use them, let us all know.

Comment: Thanks @Aml Ill have a look at their service agreement's

Comment: I'm using xignite and have for a couple years now.  I think they're pretty good.  They do seem to have the most flexible licensing agreement that I've come across.  I've used a few of these services over the years.

Answer (score 3):

It isn't clear from this post or your last post what data you want and what you want it for. The only thing you are going to get permission to distribute is the higher level data feeds like EOD data, or last sale (probably can't offer history).

Exchanges typically have this information available on their websites, for instance [NASDAQ Basic](http://www.nasdaqtrader.com/Trader.aspx?id=DPUSdata#db) pricing. If you want to do something like put Level 2 data up on a website for anyone to look at I think you are going to find it hard to get someone to give you a license to do that. Any exchange that would give you a license would do it in a way that would put you out of business before the ink on the contract was dry.

If you want to be in the data vending business, sign some agreements with the exchanges, hire some sales people and get selling.

Comment: I appreciate the candor everyone has had. It's a high barrier to entry for sure, and yes, ultimately it's going to be a burdensome hill to climb - a friend _recently_ recommended a check out 'BATS' data-service as they seem to be the most willing to sell data for redistribution. Haven't followed up yet...

Answer (score 0):

A few companies offer data for redistribution at more reasonable prices than directly from the exchange.

A few years back I worked on a project for an online service and they chose [QuoteMedia](http://quotemedia.com/) for their back-end feed.